# Octave/MATLAB plotting digital signals

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

Given data like this:

```
>> x = [0,3.0001,7,9];
>> y = [0 1 0 1];
>> plot(x, y);
```

I need the plot to look like a digital signal, not like a linear interpolation (see grey and blue lines).

[image]

Why?? (You don´t really need to read this):

I'm plotting events given by sensors, so I have to plot the current state of the sensors vs time. The events are not refreshed with a given frequency. I just have the times when the state of the sensors change. My data sets are something like this:

Sensor 1 On time 0

Sensor 2 On time 0.05

Sensor 1 Off time 1.15

Sensor 2 Off time 1.55

...

I don´t know if MATLAB or [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) are appropriated to plot these kind of signals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use stairs**:

```
figure;
stairs(x,y);
```

**Or**

```
x = [0,3,7,9];
y = [0 1 0 1]; % Input
```

Add this code before plotting:

```
x1(1) = x(1);
j = 2;
for i=2:numel(x)
    x1(j) = x(i);
    j =j+1;
    x1(j) = x(i);
    j=j+1;
end
x1

j = 1;
for i=1:numel(y)-1
  y1(j) = y(i);
  j =j+1;
  y1(j) = y(i);
  j=j+1;
end
y1(j) = y(end);
y1
```

Result:

```
x1 = [0, 3, 3, 7, 7, 9, 9]
y1 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]

plot(x1, y1);
```

Comment: x=[0,3.0001,7,9];
y=[0 1 0 1];
figure;stairs(x,y)

Comment: stairs is the matlab plot for this. you can use it directly. no need of any extra code.

Comment: That's a nice solution with `stairs`. You could edit it to your post above.

Comment: Why do you use explicit loops in this MATLAB program? Isn't there a way to express it using vectors and/or matrices?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is such kind of plot in MATLAB. But you can tie that plot from segments.

```
x=[0,3.0001,7,9];
y=[0 1 0 1];
ax = axes;
for iSegment = 1:numel(x)-1
    jump = y(iSegment)+1 - y(iSegment);
    line([x(iSegment) x(iSegment+1)], [y(iSegment), y(iSegment)]);
    if jump < 0
        line([x(iSegment) x(iSegment)], [y(iSegment), y(iSegment+1)]);
    elseif jump > 0
        line([x(iSegment+1) x(iSegment+1)], [y(iSegment), y(iSegment+1)]);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your sampling frequency is too low to show the sharp level changes in the signal. You can mitigate the problem by defining a vector of `x` values with a greater sampling frequency, and modifying that appropriately for your sensor on/off times. Example:

```
Ns = 1000; % number of points to use
x = linspace(0, 12, Ns);
y = zeros(1,Ns); %// initialize to all zeros
y( x >= 3 & x <= 7 ) = 1; %// signal high when x in range [3,7]
y( x > 9 ) = 1; %// signal high when x greater than 9

figure;
plot(x, y);
```